# Select subset from subset

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subset

Data has 1 table with 2 relevant fields:

- OrderNumber
- ProductID

How do I structure sql to find :-

```
 Select All OrderNumber where ProductID in (A,B)
    Now, on this subset, Select all where ProductID in (A,B,C,D,E) 
    Show CustomerName, OrderNumber, ProductID, ProductPrice
```

Goal is to find all Orders that contain 2 specific products, then to measure sales of only 3 specific products related to A,B.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but I will take a stab.

This will show you the details of orders with one of the 5 product id's

```
 SELECT CustomerName, OrderNumber, ProductID, ProductPrice
 FROM yourTable
 WHERE ProductId IN ('A','B','C','D','E')
```

This will count the orders for you

```
 SELECT ProductID, COUNT(*) AS Count
 FROM yourTable
 WHERE ProductId IN ('A','B','C','D','E')
 GROUP BY ProductId
```